# I want to remove the engine for rebuilding and boring

Tags: mitsubishi, outlander, engine-removal

Yesterday I started disassembling the attachment from the 4b11 engine of the Mitsubishi Outlander 3 2.0 petrol engine, I ask for your advice on how I can remove it from the car more conveniently, so that the gearbox remains on the body, and remove only the motor, what sequence to follow when unscrewing the bolts, I’m doing it for the first time. Thanks for understanding. The car is standing without a pit and a lift